# How to resolve MISRA C:2012 error regarding to memcpy function?

Tags: c, embedded, misra

I am using standard memcpy function which declared in string.h file thus:

```
extern void *   memcpy(void *, const void *, size_t);
```

**Case 1** : 
My code is compiled without any error or warnings.

```
const uint8_t *buff = (uint8_t*)Getbuff();
uint8_t data[3] = {0};
memcpy((void*)data,(const void*)(buff+2),3U);
```

After checking MISRA C:2012 I am getting following MISRA error:

> performing pointer arithmetic via addition 
>       [MISRA 2012 Rule 18.4, advisory] `memcpy((void*)data,(const void*)(buff+2),3U);`

**Case 2** : 
If I fix MISRA error in Case 1 thus:

```
const uint8_t *buff = (uint8_t*)Getbuff();
uint8_t data[3] = {0};
memcpy((void*)data,(const void*)(buff[2]),3U);
```

I am getting compile time warning and a different MISRA error.

Compile time warning :

```
cast to pointer from integer of different size
```

MISRA error:

> explicit cast from `'const UINT8'` (aka `'const unsigned char'`) to 
>       `'const void *'` [MISRA 2012 Rule 11.6, required]`memcpy((void*)data,(const void*)(buffer[2]),3U);`

Comment: The second case is not identical to the first case! You take a byte value (buff[2] = 0...255) as an address.

Comment: `buff[2]` is not `&buff[2]`, that's what the second warning is telling you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just;

```
memcpy( data, &buff[2], 3u ) ;
```

Both the pointer arithmetic and casts are unnecessary and contrary to MISRA rules.

To cast to a `void*` rather misunderstands the purpose of a void-pointer, and casting in general can suppress essential warnings that the compiler might otherwise issue.  The resulting de-clutter makes the code much easier to read *and* MISRA compliant.

Your second case was also semantically incorrect, and would not have resulted in correct behaviour - warnings are not always just *warnings*; often they indicate semantic errors.  For the compiler "*error*" just means "*cannot be compiled*" (syntactic error); a *semantic* error is one where the code does not do what was intended.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you change the pointer arithmetics

```
buff+2
```

in the first case to

```
&(buff[2])
```

the MISRA warning should go away.

Or in other words: add the &-operator in case 2.